# how to properly initialize shared resource in kotlintest 2.x (interceptSpec)

Tags: kotlin, kotlintest

I'm trying to do a standard `beforeAll`/`afterAll` type setup in the unit tests, but am having some problems.  It seems like the [`interceptSpec`](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/blob/master/doc/reference.md#intercepting-a-spec%20interceptSpec) functionality is what I want and the documentation explicitly mentions this is good for e.g. cleaning up database resources, but I can't find a good example. Code below:

```
class MyTest : StringSpec() {
    lateinit var foo: String

    override fun interceptSpec(context: Spec, spec: () -> Unit) {
        foo = "foo"
        println("before spec - $foo")
        spec()
        println("after spec - $foo")
    }

    init {
        "some test" {
            println("inside test - $foo")
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the below output:

```
before spec - foo
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property foo has not been initialized
    ... stack trace omitted ...
after spec - foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kotlintest` 2.x creates new instance of test case for every test. You can either cancel that behaviour clearing flag:

```
override val oneInstancePerTest = false
```

Or explicitly add your interceptors to test:

```
val withFoo: (TestCaseContext, () -> Unit) -> Unit = { context, spec ->
    foo = "foo"
    spec()
}

init {
    "some test" {
        println("inside test - $foo")
    }.config(interceptors = listOf(withFoo))
}
```